Error: AccountNotFound: on Solana CLI
So I setup Solana CLI on Ubuntu (Windows sub system WSL2).
I started up my solana-test-validator
Then I opened up a new Linux terminal instance and set solana config set --url localhost
Finally I created my wallet:
solana-keygen new -o /home/candid/.config/solana/id.json

I set passphrase and got the following info:
Wrote new keypair to /home/candid/.config/solana/id.json
pubkey: 6sgA73Uu6Ww8sFAt4h48ruqYgtuDK9F4Q3px72qnr7mw

I was able to check my account balance, do an airdrop, and confirm my address using the balance, airdrop, and address commands.
But if I try to use: solana account 6sgA73Uu6Ww8sFAt4h48ruqYgtuDK9F4Q3px72qnr7mw --config /home/candid/.config/solana/id.json
then I always get:
Error: AccountNotFound: pubkey=6sgA73Uu6Ww8sFAt4h48ruqYgtuDK9F4Q3px72qnr7mw

Is this expected behavior when running the test validator? How do I make it not give that error?
If I use: solana account 6sgA73Uu6Ww8sFAt4h48ruqYgtuDK9F4Q3px72qnr7mw
Then I get:
Public Key: 6sgA73Uu6Ww8sFAt4h48ruqYgtuDK9F4Q3px72qnr7mw
Balance: 500000032 SOL
Owner: 11111111111111111111111111111111
Executable: false
Rent Epoch: 18446744073709551615


The --config option should be a yml file, when you don't want to use the default config, not a keypair.
